# how to get the latest record of data in phpmyadmin database (laravel)?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

This is value inside my table.

```
    id  branch_id  name    qty     datetime
    --- ---------  ----    ----    -----------
    1   1           a      5       2017-07-28 12:26:01
    2   2           b      3       2017-07-28 12:26:02
    3   3           c      4       2017-07-28 12:26:03
    4   1           a      2       2017-07-29 12:26:04
    5   2           b      2       2017-07-29 12:26:05
    6   3           c      2       2017-07-29 12:26:06
```

I want it to be displayed as

```
    id  branch_id  name    qty     datetime
    --- ---------  ----    ----    -----------
    4   1           a      2       2017-07-29 12:26:04
```

I would like to get the latest DateTime of the item when the login user branch_id is 1, therefore only show the details of branch_id 1.

I tried the code shown below but it returns the old record, not the latest one.

```
     DB::table('A')
        ->leftJoin('B', 'A.id', '=', 'B.id')
        ->where('A.id', Auth::user()->id)
        ->groupby('name')
        ->order_by('B.datetime', 'desc')
        ->get();
```

Can I know what's the problem?
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71f834/5

Comment: Why you left joined the B table?

Comment: To get some details from table B

Comment: it's `groupBy and orderBy` and then use `->get()`

Comment: Could you please put your query result as well?

Comment: Yes, i did it. But it return the old record not the newest.

Comment: My query result return all the product with datetime 2017-07-28 12:26:07

Comment: That might be happening because the current user id is the one that matched your where clause condition

Comment: Try to put ->first() :-?

Comment: @NguyenHoang will return error with get non property of object

Comment: @AmrAly i dont get it.

Comment: what i mean according to your table example if the current authenticated user id for example is 1, 2 or 3 you will always get old records because your where clause grab only the user with the id 1, 2 or 3. if you have multiple users try to change the logged in user and see if the results will change or not

Comment: @AmrAly i am not going to get the latest record from the other user, i only need the latest record for current user.

Comment: But in your example you said you want a collection of records `4, 5, 6` . anyway instead of using `get()` use `first()`

Comment: first() will return 'Trying to get property of non-object'.

Answer (score 0):

Set an alias for the table and then use the required alias on the orderBy

```
DB::table('firsttable as A')
    ->leftJoin('secondtable as B', 'A.id', '=', 'B.id')
    ->where('A.id', Auth::user()->id)
    ->orderBy('B.datetime', 'desc')
    ->groupBy('name')->get();
```

Comment: I did that, the result is samee.

Comment: Try to use orderBy before groupBy.

Comment: problem stlll same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. This looks weird because we're using JOIN in one table but it works.

```
$query = DB::select('
    SELECT n1.*
    FROM   mytable n1
           LEFT JOIN mytable n2
               ON (n1.branch_id = n2.branch_id AND n1.id < n2.id)
    WHERE  n2.id IS NULL;
');
```

Comment: Sorry, can i know where should i put this?

Comment: @Zidance, I deeply review your sample codes again and I wonder if you really like to get the latest data. First, you want to get data with `qty` of `5`, `4`, `3` but in the database you have it's not the latest inserts. Second, remove the `join` and `where condition`, you don't need it based on your expected output.

Comment: i updated my sample table, i made some mistake on what i exactly want.

Comment: i use join due to need get details from other table as well

Comment: @Zidance, again so you want to `qty` of 5? It's not the latest insert again. If yes. Then you just need this.    `$query = DB::table('users as A')
        ->leftJoin('test as B', 'A.id', '=', 'B.id')
        ->where('A.id', Auth::user()->id)
        ->select('b.*')
        ->get();`

Comment: I am not looking for last inserted single record, i am trying to get all the branch_id details which is with the latest datetime. E.g. i will only need to display the latest details with branch_id if there is duplicate id_branch. If there branch id - 1,2,3 on 28th and branch id -1,2,3 on 29th, i need to display the 29th details of branch.

Comment: I see, so your expected result needs to be updated again. Give me sec.

Comment: Please check my edit on your question. Let me know if it's correct.

Comment: Yeah, i want to show like this, but i keep showing the old record, i have no idea.

Comment: If you want to show what you think the expected results are, please edit your answer to show any assumptions you have made and not edit the original question.

Comment: is there any solution?

Comment: Sorry for late response. I thought somebody solved it. I've updated my answer and post there the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will you:

```
DB::table('A')
        ->leftJoin('B', 'A.name', '=', 'B.name')
        ->where('A.id', '>',B.id)
        ->order_by('B.datetime', 'desc')
        ->get();
```

Raw Query [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aeabf9/25)

I just removed the group by and use `.name` column into `leftjoin`

Comment: is that the same way to do it if referring to multiple table?

Comment: @Zidance: Not getting the point, Your question belongs to single table query. Can you please show your multiple table query with new question.

Comment: The branch_id is FK which use to connect another table.

Comment: I want something like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71f834/5, but return the latest datetime.

Comment: @Zidance, I don't understand. My answer doesn't work?

Comment: @VandolphReyes: Please place your comments/arguments into your answer. This will interrupt the communication with OP

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd, my bad. He doesn't response anymore on our comments.

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd why need to put  where A.id > B.id ?

Comment: @Zidance: You can see the reason by comment that line, please check

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd just want get to know, Is this applicable for more than 2 table?

Comment: @Zidance: Quick question:
1) Your given demo having multiple table? I think yes
2) My solution query for you? I think yes
3) Now, please clarify your question: "just want get to know, Is this applicable for more than 2 table?"

Comment: @Zidance: Hope you got your solution. You can upvote/accept to close this question.

Comment: @Zidance: Please accept this answer if you got the solution, so other people can get the right answer